# How to add content to above email template assigned to Triggered Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, triggered-send

I have managed to initiate the Triggered Email using AMPscript in a Cloud page.

Is there a way to pass in text content into the Triggered Send above the email assigned to the Triggered Email functionality? So it will appear in the email message above the email template assigned to the Triggered Email. I believe it will need to happen as the Triggered Send is initiated as it will potentially change with each send depending on the information passed into it. I can also use SSJS if that is a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it'll require that you add some AMPscript code to your email (or template) -- code that retrieves the value from an attribute coming over in the API payload.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
%%[

var @topContent
set @topContent = AttributeValue("topContent")

]%%
%%=v(@topContent)=%%
<!-- the rest of the email HTML -->
</body>
</html>
```

Where `topContent` is the attribute specified in your CloudPage code to trigger the email.